# How to kill a program with esc or a button Java

Tags: java, swing, exit

I want my program to run but once esc is pressed to quit the program. The only way I can think of doing this is by doing a scanner and looking for the next line but that pauses the whole program. Maybe a key listener but how do I make it be constantly checking? And it is a GUI. Any help would be great!

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

stop = sc.nextLine();

if (stop.equals(a)){
running = false;
}
else{
do program
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I could accept answers. I went back and did that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u use a frame you can register the keys.

```
myFrame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "EXIT"); 
    myFrame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("EXIT", new AbstractAction(){ 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            myFrame.dispose();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked great. But what if the screen is minimized. How do I make it exit out then

Comment: mm try you should see `WindowListener` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is a UI, you should not be maintaining any kind of loop that could block the Event Dispatching Thread.

The EDT will dispatch key events to your program and you can respond to them if you have registered for notifications.

I would avoid `KeyListener` as it requires the component it is registered to be focused and have keyboard focus before it will respond.

Instead, I would use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

You can register a <kbd>Escape</kbd> key to either the main application window (or sub component) or directly with the `JButton` you are using to close the application with.